# how to Read data from Excel and put them in a dictionary?

Tags: testcomplete

I am using Testcomplete software and C# scripting.

I am able to read the data from the excel but I am not able to put them in a dictionary.So seeking help.

Comment: Do you mean a C# dictionary? How are you planning to use it?

Comment: I want to create in c # scripting,I have to store the data in dictionary and then i have to pass that dictionary to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#Script is based on the Microsoft JScript language (the same as JavaScript). Objects in this language behave in the same way as Dictionary objects and so you can use this functionality without any problems:

```
  var dict = new Object();
  dict["MyKey1"] = ["Obj1Val1", "Obj1Val2"];
  dict["MyKey2"] = ["Obj2Val1", "Obj2Val2"];
  dict["MyKey3"] = ["Obj3Val1", "Obj3Val2"];
  Log.Message(dict["MyKey2"][1]);
```